# Vim doesn't extend Roxygen R comments

Tags: insert-mode, comments

I'd like it if, when filling out my Roxygen comment snippet,

```
#' Title     
#'           
#' @param    
#'           
#' @return   
#'           
#' @examples 
#'           
#'           
#' @export
```

vim would extend the `#'` when I press return on a line.

I figure I need to do something with `:setlocal comments`, but I haven't been able to figure out what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/r.vim` (Windows: `$HOME/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/r.vim`) with the following content:

```
setlocal formatoptions+=r
```

This file is sourced, after Vims filetype specific file for R is sourced. So it can be used to change settings that are from the R file type plugin or to add other things that you want to do when loading a R file (like define specific mappings etc).

If you only want to change the `formatoptions` you could also add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType r setlocal formatoptions+=r
```

The added formatoption `r` means:

> Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting <Enter> in Insert mode.

Comment: Thank you! The equivalent file in neovim is `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/r.vim`.